# La función streamplot no dibuja líneas de corriente donde quiero

Tags: python, matplotlib

mi problema es que quiero plotear líneas de corriente y barbas de viento en un mapa, para ello tengo los archivos netcdf U y V pero el problema es que cuando intento plotear los datos se dibuja solo en la región de África y Asia cosa que no me interesa, me interesa que se dibujen las líneas en todos los continentes o por lo menos en la región del continente americano.

Adjunto el script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import cartopy.feature as feature
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy.ma as ma

u1250 = Dataset('u2-12.nc')
v1250 = Dataset('v2-12.nc')
lon = u1250.variables['lon'][:]
lat = u1250.variables['lat'][:]

u0 = u1250.variables['uwnd'][0, :, :]
u_units = u1250.variables['uwnd'].units

v0 = v1250.variables['vwnd'][0, :, :]
v_units = v1250.variables['vwnd'].units

x,y = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)
u00=ma.squeeze(u0)
v00=ma.squeeze(v0)

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.add_feature(feature.COASTLINE, linewidth=1.5)
ax.add_feature(feature.BORDERS, linewidth=1.5)

ax.streamplot(x, y, u00, v00, density=5, color='k', linewidth=2)
ax.stock_img()
plt.barbs(x, y, u00, v00, pivot='middle',barbcolor='red',length=4.2, linewidth = 0.15)
plt.show()
```

Con lo anterior obtengo esto de la imagen, las barbas se colocan bien, pero las líneas no.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los archivos los tengo en mi drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1pDGlb_AjK1lJfIp5eFORpweafPUKfJVe?usp=sharing

Si alguien sabe como arreglar esto, me serviría mucho, gracias!